# What is the lists of fillcolor in Overleaf Latex for bar graph? How to change the default color of bar graph?

Tags: pgfplots, color, bar-chart

How can I change the default colour of Overleaf graph template?

[image]

I found a list of colour

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \X in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\X=1
\edef\mylst{Testing1}
\else
\edef\mylst{\mylst,Testing\X}
\fi}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords/.expanded=\mylst,
    ylabel=Number,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    x tick label style={anchor=north west,rotate=-30},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(Testing1,9) (Testing2,4)
         (Testing3,4) (Testing4,1) (Testing5,1) (Testing6,8) (Testing7,1) (Testing8,1) (Testing9,1)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(Testing1,3) (Testing2,5)
         (Testing3,5) (Testing4,4) (Testing5,5) (Testing6,7) (Testing7,0) (Testing8,0) (Testing9,0)};
\legend{Series 1, Series2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See the documentation of  `xcolor` (you also have `svgnames` and `x11names`).

Comment: @Bernard. Thanks. I did search `https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors`. but I have no idea how to add code in my bar graph

Comment: Here is a link for [xcolor documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor). See the § Colors by names.

Comment: With `pstricks` (see my answer to your previous question), it was in the preamble the definitions of the two `barstyle`s , e.g.: `\newpsbarstyle{colora}{fillcolor=CornflowerBlue!90, fillstyle=solid, framearc=0}`. Just change the name of the colour on  `fillcolor=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default colors have nothing to do with overleaf but they are stored in cycle lists. The relevant cycle list for `ybar` (which is the same for `xbar`) can be found on p. 86 of the manual v1.16,

[image]

You can change it to get e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{
/pgfplots/bar cycle list/.style={/pgfplots/cycle list={
{OliveGreen,fill=OliveGreen!30!white,mark=none},
{Plum,fill=Plum!30!white,mark=none},
{cyan!60!black,fill=cyan!30!white,mark=none},
{black,fill=gray,mark=none},
},
},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \X in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\X=1
\edef\mylst{Testing1}
\else
\edef\mylst{\mylst,Testing\X}
\fi}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords/.expanded=\mylst,
    ylabel=Number,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    x tick label style={anchor=north west,rotate=-30},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar,
]
\addplot 
    coordinates {(Testing1,9) (Testing2,4)
         (Testing3,4) (Testing4,1) (Testing5,1) (Testing6,8) (Testing7,1) (Testing8,1) (Testing9,1)};
\addplot 
    coordinates {(Testing1,3) (Testing2,5)
         (Testing3,5) (Testing4,4) (Testing5,5) (Testing6,7) (Testing7,0) (Testing8,0) (Testing9,0)};
\legend{Series 1, Series2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I loaded `xcolor` with the `dvipsnames` option to get your fancy colors in, you could also use `\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}` before `\usepackage{pgfplots}` since it loads `xcolor` anyway.

Alternatively you can pass the options directly to `\addplot`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.16}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \X in {1,...,9}
{\ifnum\X=1
\edef\mylst{Testing1}
\else
\edef\mylst{\mylst,Testing\X}
\fi}
\begin{axis}[symbolic x coords/.expanded=\mylst,
    ylabel=Number,
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    x tick label style={anchor=north west,rotate=-30},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ybar,
]
\addplot[fill=ForestGreen!30,draw=ForestGreen] 
    coordinates {(Testing1,9) (Testing2,4)
         (Testing3,4) (Testing4,1) (Testing5,1) (Testing6,8) (Testing7,1) (Testing8,1) (Testing9,1)};
\addplot[fill=RoyalPurple!30,draw=RoyalPurple]  
    coordinates {(Testing1,3) (Testing2,5)
         (Testing3,5) (Testing4,4) (Testing5,5) (Testing6,7) (Testing7,0) (Testing8,0) (Testing9,0)};
\legend{Series 1, Series2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use any of the colors of your list, of course.